# SELECT clause using 3 different tables

Tags: sql, oracle

Having these 3 tables

DEPARTMENT

```
 //DEPARTMENT
 DNAME
 -----------
 RESEARCH
    IT
  SCIENCE
```

PROJECT

```
//PROJECT
P#      TITLE
----------------
1      COMPUTING
2       CODING
3       SEARCHING
```

DP <-- Assume constraint references done, just i didn't show the code here

```
 //DP
 DNAME        P#
 ---------------
 RESEARCH     1
   IT         2
 RESEARCH     3
```

When using this statement

```
SELECT d.DNAME,P.TITLE FROM DEPARTMENT d 
      INNER JOIN PROJECT 
      INNER JOIN DP ON d.DNAME=DP.DNAME AND P.P#=DP.P#;
```

How should i change in order to get output like this, only show the DNAME that have projects

```
DNAME         TITLES
---------------------
RESEARCH     COMPUTING
RESEARCH     SEARCHING
   IT         CODING
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this query

```
SELECT d.DNAME,P.TITLE from DEPARTMENT d
  INNER JOIN DP ON d.DNAME=DP.DNAME
  INNER JOIN PROJECT P ON P.P#=DP.P#
order by d.DNAME DESC, P.TITLE ASC
```

Comment: everyone deserves an upvote for their selected answer right? ;)

Answer (score 0):

Your `DEPARTMENT` data is already there in `DP` table. So use it.

```
select DNAME, TITLE
from DP d, PROJECT p
where d.p# = p.p#
order by 1
```

Answer (score 0):

you could also try :

**MYSQL syntax:**

```
SELECT d.DNAME,P.TITLE from DEPARTMENT d
  INNER JOIN PROJECT P
  INNER JOIN DP ON d.DNAME=DP.DNAME AND P.P#=DP.P#
order by d.DNAME DESC, P.TITLE ASC
```

[Running fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/43b4c/5)

**SQL syntax**

```
SELECT d.dname,p.title from DEPARTMENT d,PROJECT P
  ,DP where d.DNAME=DP.DNAME and
  P.P#=DP.P#
order by d.dname desc, P.title asc
```

[Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/43b4c/15).

i have no clue why an inner join with three tables and an on condition in the last inner join does not work with `MYSQL`. Glad though that you have found a solution.

Comment: although no down-vote, they provided the table names and you ignored them with table names t1, t2, t3...  I suggest adjusting it.

Comment: when i try your code , your code having error at missing keywords at order bgy there

Comment: @user3553846 The syntax used in the query is of MySQL. In order to make it work on Oracle you need to specify ON clause after each inner join. Take a look at my answer